# Calculate $\iint \sqrt{2-x^2-y^2} \, dx \, dy$ over the circle $x^2+y^2=x\sqrt{2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

so as my question states I have to calculate

$$\iint_\limits A \sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy$$ where $A$ is the circle defined by

$$x^2+y^2=x\sqrt{2}$$

After introducing polar coordinates $(x = r\cos\theta, y= r\sin\theta)$, I get that:

The left side of the equation of the circle is always nonnegative, so the right side also has to be nonnegative. This means that $x \ge 0$, or

$$\theta \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right].$$

Also we have that

$$r=\sqrt{2} \cos\theta$$

Here's where I have a slight problem. If I think about it, $2-x^2-y^2$ has to be $\ge 0$ for the square root to be real. Now, that means that $r \le \sqrt{2}$.

How do I determine the boundaries of $r$? I think that the boundaries for $r$ are $r \in [\sqrt{2}\cos\theta, \sqrt{2}]$. If yes, could anyone explain why exactly? I'm confused because I don't have an inequality in $r=\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are almost there. You need to integrate over the circle $x^2 + y^2 \leq \sqrt2 x$.

So as you said, $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt2 \cos\theta, - \frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

The integrand is $\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2} = \sqrt{2-r^2}$

and as $r \leq \sqrt2 \cos\theta, \theta \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right] \ , \  $  we have $\ r \leq \sqrt2$

So the integrand is defined in the entire region and the integral in polar coordinates is,

$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt2 \cos\theta} r \ \sqrt{2-r^2} \ dr \ d\theta$$

Comment: how can I know that the boundaries for $r$ are $0, \sqrt{2}\cos\theta$? For example I got that $r$ is both less than $\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$, and less than $\sqrt{2}$, but I don't know which one of those is the upper bound.

If $r$ is less than both of those values, then the upper bound for $r$ is the smaller of the two. I don't know which one is smaller!

Comment: The integrand is just a scalar function that we are integrating over the given region. The integrand does not influence the bounds of the integral. The bound should be decided by the region which is the given circle.

Comment: @l0ner9 : Are you not aware that as $\theta$ goes from $-\pi/2$ to $+\pi/2,$ $\cos\theta$ goes from $0$ up to $1$ and then back down to $0$? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy now that you say it, I am!

Comment: @l0ner9 I hope it is all clear now. Feel free to ask whatever questions you got :)